# Flask keeps executing the same old code even after replacing the code with new one

Tags: python, flask

I am extremely new to flask framework. I wrote a few basic beginner codes in flask and after I did the changes to it, the output doesn't change as is the same code is running behind the scene which I can't figure out.

I Tried:-

Changing the directory of my python file.
Deleting the file and made a new one.
Deleting the browser cache and cookies.

This seems to be a common issue but there's no perfect answer for this question on this site, please help.

Sample code:

```
from flask import Flask , redirect , url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello bc"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: When you stop and restart the Flask localhost server, what happens?

Comment: Nothing very distinctive, just like how it ran for the first time without any error or warning

Answer (score 3):

I opened the task manager to check if there was any process related to the flask running in the background and ended up closing all the python processes that were running in the background and it's working fine now thanks for the replies.

Comment: Although being very odd, this is the working solution. It seems that Flask keeps running in the background when closed ungracefully, in some cases, such as when started with multiprocessing. That only seems to happen on windows, as its multiprocessing doesnt support forking, and spawns a new process instead.

Answer (score 0):

first of all enable the debug *true* that helps

```
 app.run(debug=True)
```

This will display flask restarting in the terminal when you update the code.

Second, try hard refresh of the browser by pressing ***CTRL+SHIFT+R***

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's no change

Comment: have you opened it in another browser? 
Also try the incognito mode. Pretty sure it is the cache issue

Answer (score 0):

For sake of better coding and work with flask in future id suggest you setting up venv variablies like FLASK_APP=app.py , FLASK_DEBUG=1. And using flask run in your terminal.

Im not sure wich OS you are using on windows u can use set FLASK_DEBUG=1 , on linux just replace set with export FLASK_DEBUG=1.